# pretty printing Calendar in lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I use lombok and it it is really great!
However if I print beans that contain Calendar properties it prints the Calendar object (of course...) and it is really confusing to see the value of the Calendar. I can see something like

```
ScheduledEvent(id=1, scheduledStartDate=java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1492032183000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Budapest",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=151,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Budapest,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=15,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=12,DAY_OF_YEAR=102,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE=23,SECOND=3,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000], ...
```

Is it possible to assign a SimpleDateFormat to the Calendar somehow (e.g. if lombok meets the Calendar object then uses this formatter) and having a simple value like '2016-34-34T12:12:12.543'?

Thanks,
V.

Comment: No, Lombok can only include the field or ignore it. If the field is included, then `toString` gets used, except for arrays. There are a few related feature requests, e.g., [this one by me](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/project-lombok/dc5nXTI3xMU/uNPwONfcAQAJ). +++ If you're on Java 8, I'd strongly suggest you use the `java.time` package.

Comment: ok, thanks Maartinus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to lombok but rather the `toString()` implementation of `GregorianCalendar`.

If you want to do anything about it you have several options:

- use `LocalDateTime` or any of the new Time API classes which also have a more beautiful `toString()` output
- wrap `GregorianCalendar`-instances in objects of your own and implement `toString()` of that wrapper class yourself
- don't let lombok generate `toString()` for `ScheduledEvent` but rather provide your own implementation
- modify lombok to handle `GregorianCalendar` the way you like

Comment: Hi Markus, thanks for the reply! I thought there is a nice annotation or a parameter of the ToString annotation. Any of the recommended solution can work but none of them is perfect. Would it be worth to add this option to lombok...?

Answer (score 12):

I know this post is two years ago but now there is a better soluce.

Let lombok generate the **toString()** method, annotade your field with **@ToString.Exclude** and create a method with this annotation: **@ToString.Include(name = "yourVariable")**.

Here is an example:

```
@Data
public class ScheduledEvent {
    private int id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    private GregorianCalendar scheduledStartDate;
    // etc ...

    @ToString.Include(name = "scheduledStartDate")
    private String formatScheduledStartDate() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(scheduledStartDate.getTime());
    }
}
```

And the **toString()** method returns in this case:

```
ScheduledEvent(id=1, scheduledStartDate=2019-03-04)
```